# Is it proper to describe a noun using an apostrophe?

Tags: apostrophe, writing

For example, if I wanted to say, "This student is large.", would it be proper to instead say, "This student's large."? I don't recall ever reading something like this, but I remember hearing people speak like this. Is this purely a speaking shortcut or is it also proper to write as well?

Comment: It's valid in reported speech or in informal writing.  Not generally valid in formal writing.

Answer (score -1):

No, it would be grammatically incorrect.Apostrophe are used to signify possession, except in the following cases: it's and that's. Here it's means it is and that's stands for that is

e.g it's going to be fun.(Here it's means it is)

e.g The jam is past its expiry date (its used as a possessive)

Comment: Not true. As @HotLicks says, _is_ after a noun is often contracted in speech, though it would be incorrect to do so in formal writing.

Comment: It is grammatically incorrect to write.That is what I meant when I said that it's grammatically incorrect.